# RxSwift: How to correctly subscribe to a variable change

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have two screens:

1. `NewControlTableViewController`: contains a textfield for selecting a client from the other view
2. `ClientsTableViewController`: The second view contains a list clients that can be selected

[image]
[image]

The two screens share a viewmodel.

So here is my code:

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
struct NewControlViewModel {
     var selectedClient = Variable<Client>(Client())
     // other stuff
}
// NewControlTableViewController : viewDidLoad
viewModel.selectedClient.asObservable().subscribe { event in
        debugPrint(event)
}
// ClientsTableViewController: viewDidLoad

/*tableView.rx.itemSelected.subscribe(onNext: { indexPath in
        let client = self.clients[indexPath.row]
        debugPrint(client)
        self.viewModel.selectedClient.value = client
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

    }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)*/
   // new code
   tableView.rx
        .modelSelected(Client.self)
        .debug("client selected", trimOutput: true)
        .do(onNext: { _ in
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        })
        .subscribe(onNext: { client in
            debugPrint(client)
            self.viewModel.selectedClient.value = client
        }, onError: { error in
        debugPrint(error)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The event is fired(with empty values) whenever I view the first screen, then, after selecting a client from the second screen, for some reason, no event is being fired.

Comment: Are you forgetting to use `.disposed(by:)` in `NewControlTableViewController`?

Comment: The `dispose` method is for disposing the streams after the controller has been deallocated. Not important in this case ! :)

Comment: Are you sure you are not mutating `selectedClient` somewhere along the way? Make it a `let` to check.

Comment: could you please explain more. I didnt get your question

Comment: @TimofeySolonin I need `selectedClient` as mutable so I can change it later, when the user select a client.

Comment: @PraviJay I have a form and I need when the user select the first row and select a client (from the second view), I need to get that selected client and fill the first row (of the 1st view) with it. That's way I need to get notified whenever the user select a client. I hope this will make my question clear for you :)

Comment: @SahbiBelgacem `selectedClient` is already mutable in its `value` field. I tried replicating your scenario and it works correctly for me. My only guess is you are reinstantiating the `selectedClient` itself somewhere which makes it a different from the object you subscribed to. 

By any means you shouldn't mutate the `selectedClient` because it goes against the `Variable` logic of having mutable parameter represented by the immutable object.

Comment: @SahbiBelgacem could you share the code where you mutate the `selectedClient`?

Comment: @TimofeySolonin please see my updated code in my initial post

Comment: @SahbiBelgacem is there any chance you reassign `viewModel.selectedClient` (not viewModel.selectedClient.value) anywhere?

Comment: @TimofeySolonin nope :( I've checked !

Comment: @SahbiBelgacem are you sure you are passing the same `viewModel` you subscribe to?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that too :) . I'm curently "converting" all my tableviewcontrollers into viewcontrollers, hoping that will somehow fix my problem !

Comment: "self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)" that could deinit the controller and their properties. May be that could be the issue. because "do(onNext: { _ in " call first. check it without using that just for once.

Comment: @PraviJay I removed the `do` block and inserted `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` into the `subscribe` block but nothing happened :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `Variables` are deprecated.

You should use a `PublishRelay` which doesn't need an initial value, that way it won't be fired upon subscription in your first screen.
The advantage of Relays is they don't error out or complete.

```
struct NewControlViewModel {
  let selectedClient = PublishRelay<Client>()
}

// NewControlTableViewController : viewDidLoad
choisirMandat.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in
  let viewController = /* instantiate vc */

  // Make sure to use the same viewModel
  viewController.viewModel = self.viewModel

  self.present(viewController, animated: true)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)

self.viewModel.selectedClient.debug().subscribe().disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

// ClientsTableViewController: viewDidLoad
tableView.rx.itemSelected.map { [unowned self] indexPath in
  return self.clients[indexPath.row]
}
.debug("client selected", trimOutput: true)
.do(onNext: { [unowned self] _ in
  self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
})
.bind(to: self.viewModel.selectedClient)
.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

On a side note, clients should probably also come from the Rx world if you want to be fully functional.
Second side note, you can use the `debug()` operator to print events.

`bind(to:)` was added in RxSwift 4.1 so make sure to be up to date

Comment: My problem was with using **2 differents instances of the same `viewModel` object**. Instead of doing that, I will pass the the viewModel object to `ClientsViewController` 's viewModel object, so now both share the same instance !

Answer (score -1):

I think I have found your issue here. You are doing is

```
// NewControlTableViewController : viewDidLoad
viewModel.selectedClient.asObservable().subscribe { event in
    debugPrint(event)
}
 // ClientsTableViewController: viewDidLoad

tableView.rx.itemSelected.subscribe(onNext: { indexPath in
    let client = self.clients[indexPath.row]
    debugPrint(client)
    self.viewModel.selectedClient.value = client
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

}).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

You need to change this line "self.viewModel.selectedClient.value = client". You need to use previous controller instance or NewControlTableViewController instance like self.newControlTableVC.selectedClient.value = client

I think you are trying to use viewmodel by sending there value from NewControlTableViewController to ClientsTableViewController.

Moreover, I did the same scenario which you did and it worked very well in my case. Just try my scenario if it could not work there must be some minor issue.

I hope it may help

Comment: This is just wrong. Try making a scenario like the one described in the OP's post and it works as expected. When struct is passed over it replicates all of the contained reference type.

Comment: @TimofeySolonin Hey you are right. I did the same scenario and it worked for me.